# Jinja2 not displaying the images

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I got a problem displaying photos from my uploads folder.
I have a form where user can enter title, description and upload a image, then insert it into database. I can display all the data I just added on my template except the image, there just a X instead of image.

ps. image is successfully downloaded to uploads folder and it filename successfully added to database. It just doesnt display on the page.

app.py

```
#route to content page
@app.route('/dashboard', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard():
    error = None
    form = MessageForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        filename = secure_filename(form.photo.data.filename)
        form.photo.data.save(os.path.join('uploads/', filename))
        new_message = BlogPost(
            form.title.data,
            form.description.data,
            form.photo.data.filename,
            current_user.id
        )
        db.session.add(new_message)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Your recipe was successfully posted. Thanks!")
        posts = db.session.query(BlogPost).all()
        return render_template('dashboard.html', posts = posts, form = form,
                               error = error)
    else:
        posts = db.session.query(BlogPost).all()
        return render_template('dashboard.html', posts = posts, form = form,    
                               error = error)
```

template

```
  {% for post in posts %}
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-5 masonry-item"> 
    <div class="box-masonry"><a href="#" title="" class="box-masonry
     image with-hover-overlay">
    <img src="uploads/{{ post.photo }}" alt="" class="img-responsive"
     </a>
      <div class="box-masonry-hover-text-header"> 
        <h4> <a href="#">{{ post.title }}</a></h4>
        <div class="box-masonry-desription">
          <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
          <p><strong>{{ post.author.name }}</strong></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Works fine when I point it manualy,  but obviesly I want it dynamic...

Comment: Think you need a relative path, try `/uploads/`

Comment: Tried that already, doesnt help.

Comment: is it properly placed in a static folder? try `{{ url_for('static', filename ='uploads\'+post.photo) }}`

Comment: It works... Jesus. I tried that before and it didnt work, I dont understand. Thanks alot mate!

Answer (score 2):

From the Flask [Doc](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#static-files) :

> To generate URLs for static files, use the special 'static' endpoint
>   name:
>
> `url_for('static', filename='style.css')`
>
> The file has to be stored on the filesystem as static/style.css.

And in your case you should use:

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + post.photo) }}
```